# Long data with uneven time

Tags: stata

I have a long dataset but observations have  different time lengths.  I would like to have even time lengths for each observation (12 months). This implies adding a zero value for new observations that will allow to balance the dataset.

I have an example below:[image]

I would like a Stata code that allows me to get the below data:

[image]

Comment: Posting a data example as an image is not nearly as helpful as you hope or intend. Posting what looks like something from Excel as illustration of a Stata problem is also not a good idea. Please study the `stata` tag wiki for detailed advice on how to post a data example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`tsfill` can do this for you. It's arguably easier than business calendars.

If China is the only country in your dataset:

```
. /* Time-Series Example */
. webuse tsfillxmpl, clear

. sort mdate

. list, clean noobs

    income     mdate  
      1153    1995m7  
      1181    1995m8  
      1236   1995m11  
      1297   1995m12  
      1265    1996m1  
      1282    1996m3  

. tsfill

. replace income = 0 if missing(income)
(3 real changes made)

. list, clean noobs

    income     mdate  
      1153    1995m7  
      1181    1995m8  
         0    1995m9  
         0   1995m10  
      1236   1995m11  
      1297   1995m12  
      1265    1996m1  
         0    1996m2  
      1282    1996m3
```

If you have multiple countries, you need to decide if you just want to fill in the gaps or construct a balanced panel:

```
. /* Panel Example */
. webuse tsfillxmpl2, clear

. xtset edlevel year

Panel variable: edlevel (unbalanced)
 Time variable: year, 1988 to 1992, but with a gap
         Delta: 1 unit

. sort edlevel year

. list, clean

       edlevel   year   income  
  1.         1   1988    14500  
  2.         1   1989    14750  
  3.         1   1990    14950  
  4.         1   1991    15100  
  5.         2   1989    22100  
  6.         2   1990    22200  
  7.         2   1992    22800  

. tsfill

. xtdes

 edlevel:  1, 2, ..., 2                                      n =          2
    year:  1988, 1989, ..., 1992                             T =          5
           Delta(year) = 1 unit
           Span(year)  = 5 periods
           (edlevel*year uniquely identifies each observation)

Distribution of T_i:   min      5%     25%       50%       75%     95%     max
                         4       4       4         4         4       4       4

     Freq.  Percent    Cum. |  Pattern
 ---------------------------+---------
        1     50.00   50.00 |  .1111
        1     50.00  100.00 |  1111.
 ---------------------------+---------
        2    100.00         |  XXXXX

. replace income = 0 if missing(income)
(1 real change made)

. list, clean

       edlevel   year   income  
  1.         1   1988    14500  
  2.         1   1989    14750  
  3.         1   1990    14950  
  4.         1   1991    15100  
  5.         2   1989    22100  
  6.         2   1990    22200  
  7.         2   1991        0  
  8.         2   1992    22800  

. tsfill, full

. xtdes

 edlevel:  1, 2, ..., 2                                      n =          2
    year:  1988, 1989, ..., 1992                             T =          5
           Delta(year) = 1 unit
           Span(year)  = 5 periods
           (edlevel*year uniquely identifies each observation)

Distribution of T_i:   min      5%     25%       50%       75%     95%     max
                         5       5       5         5         5       5       5

     Freq.  Percent    Cum. |  Pattern
 ---------------------------+---------
        2    100.00  100.00 |  11111
 ---------------------------+---------
        2    100.00         |  XXXXX

. replace income = 0 if missing(income)
(2 real changes made)

. list, clean

       edlevel   year   income  
  1.         1   1988    14500  
  2.         1   1989    14750  
  3.         1   1990    14950  
  4.         1   1991    15100  
  5.         1   1992        0  
  6.         2   1988        0  
  7.         2   1989    22100  
  8.         2   1990    22200  
  9.         2   1991        0  
 10.         2   1992    22800
```

Zero is not always the best value for recoding missing data. Some people favor using a large positive number that looks unusual (say 9999999). Others would suggest using a missing value, like .m or .n. I prefer the latter approach.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a Business Calendar [datetime business calendars](https://www.stata.com/manuals/ddatetimebusinesscalendars.pdf#dDatetimebusinesscalendars) then use that to drive a Merge with your observations data set, setting the value to zero where the date does not appear in your observations